# Recompiling .pyx with pyximport failed

Tags: python, cython

I wrote `fib.pyx` containing fibonacci funciton like that

```
def fib(int n):
    cdef int i
    cdef double a=0., b=1.
    for i in range(n):
        a,b = a+b, a
    return a
```

And I got pyd module with

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
import fib
```

It worked well. But when I edited `fib.pyx` a little and I tried to import it, then the change was not reflected without any error.
After I restart ipython, I tried

```
pyximport.install(reload_support=True)
import fib
fib.fib(10) # good result

# edit fib.pyx

from importlib import reload
reload(fib)
```

The reload was well because it succeeded to reload existing `fib.pyd` module. But I got the result of older fib function.

How can I recompile `fib.pyx` with `import fib`?
Is it impossible?

```
Environment: 
Python 3.4.3
Windows 7
IPython 3.2.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with [autoreload](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/autoreload.html), if it doesn't work i am afraid you have to restart the kernel process.

```
[1]: %load_ext autoreload

[2]: %autoreload 2
```

Comment: It didn't work... It seems to be good to reload the pyd module but pyximport don't compile a new pyx file.